# "TypeError: rootElement.insertBefore is not a function" getting started with React-Handsontable

Tags: reactjs, handsontable

Just getting started with Handsontable. I used `create-react-app` and `npm install --save react-handsontable`.

Added a table to `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HotTable from 'handsontable'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HotTable/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And seeing error:

```
TypeError: rootElement.insertBefore is not a function

node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.js:8197

rootElement.insertBefore(this.container, rootElement.firstChild);
```

From searching the web it seems this may have something to do with load order issues, but I'm not sure what I can change.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I was importing `handsontable` but I should have imported `react-handsontable`.

```
import HotTable from 'react-handsontable'
```

This is documented correctly but I did not notice that detail.

https://github.com/handsontable/react-handsontable